A short story called "Of Jovian Build" , who wrote it?
Who wrote the short story "Of Jovian Build"? I think it is in The Treasury of Science Fiction book.

Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. I've removed the bit in your question asking about where to find the book as that's veering close to shopping question which is not on-topic here, but asking who the author of a work is certainly is. Some more info would be helpful, have you read this before? If so, when? If not, how did you come across it?

A scan of the story, in its original publication in Thrilling Wonder Stories, is freely available at the internet archive: https://archive.org/details/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v12n02_1938-10/page/n61/mode/2up The anthology A Treasury of Science Fiction can be borrowed (also for free but registration required) from the Archive: https://archive.org/details/treasuryofscienc00conk/page/n7/mode/2up

A quick google search turns up Oscar J. Friend and it was indeed in the Treasury of Science Fiction on the Internet SF Database
Link - https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58120



Good on you for the answer. Even questions that are trivial when you know where to look can be valuable to the querent.

My copy has a different cover, and I might also have been using it as a monitor stand /s
